# MATLAB quick find of a vector in matrix

Tags: matlab, performance, search, matrix

I have a piece of code that works in the following way. 
There is a matrix of size `n x 2`. Each element is an integer between 1 and some maximum, say `m`.

I want to search for rows in this matrix, that is, given `[v1, v2]`, output the index of this.

Right now, I am using:

```
k = find(ismember(edges, [v1, v2], 'rows'));
```

However, this is the bottleneck in my code because this is in linear time.

I would like to implement some hashmap type structure for fast lookup. What would be an easy way to do this?

Comment: What is the range of `m`? Have you looked at [containers.Map](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html)?

Comment: I assume that you expect to have numerous queries that you want to speed up by doing some preprocessing, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the number of columns how about this (assuming edges is the matrix to be searched):

```
idx = find(edges(:,1)==v1 & edges(:,2)==v2);
```

Note, that depending on how exactly you use the index you might be better off using the logical index that is created on the way:

```
idx = edges(:,1)==v1 & edges(:,2)==v2;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

R2016b and beyond:

```
find(all(edges == [v1 v2], 2))
```

Prior:

```
find(all(bsxfun(@eq, edges, [v1 v2]), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
M = [5 2; 10 1; 3 2; 4 4; 5 0]
N = [4 4]
ind=find(all(repmat(N,size(M,1),1)==M,2));
```

ind is the row where the matrix include the specific numbers in N.

Answer (score 0):

Using [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) can make an adjacency matrix  to speed up  your search:

```
A = accumarray(edges,1,[m m],@any,false)
```

and you can use indexing  to search it

```
if(A(v1,v2))...
```

If `m` is very large you can create a sparse matrix:

```
A = accumarray(edges,1,[m m],@any,false,true)
```

Or if you need index of it the adjacency matrix can be cereated this way:

```
A = accumarray(edges,1:size(edgaes,1),[m m],@any,0,true);
```

so

```
index = A(v1,v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option that gives me about a 30-40 times speedup over your code is doing the comparison for the entire first column, capturing a set of indices, then only checking the values of the second column at those indices:

```
ind = find(edges(:, 1) == v1);
k = ind(edges(ind, 2) == v2);
```

If you still need it done faster than that, you can use the [`containers.Map` class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html) to precompute a mapping of every possible `[v1 v2]` to the list of row indices where it occurs. One caveat is that the key type for the map can't be a vector of numbers, but since you are dealing with integers (ideally with `m` not being prohibitively large) you can convert `[v1 v2]` to a 2-character ASCII key. Here's how you can build the map:

```
mapObj = containers.Map('KeyType', 'char', 'ValueType', 'any');
[R, C] = meshgrid(1:m);
keys = [R(:) C(:)];
for keyIndex = 1:(m*m)
  v = keys(keyIndex, :);
  ind = find(edges(:, 1) == v(1));
  mapObj(char(v)) = ind(edges(ind, 2) == v(2));
end
```

And you can access a value from the map very quickly like so:

```
k = mapObj(char([v1 v2]));
```