# MATLAB: Best way to map integers to color strings

Tags: matlab, colors, mapping

I have a list of integers that represent labels for a predictor. The list is size 2000 and contains {1,2,3,4}. How can I map these numbers to a cell array of strings that contains the values {'red','blue','green','black'}, respectively, without using loops?

I tried containers.Map, but apparently this doesn't work for vectors.

Comment: Do you mean you want a cell array size 2000 with the corresponding color string to the integer label in each row?

Comment: Yup that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by simply using your integer list as an index into the cell array of colors:

```
colors = {'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'};  % Cell array of strings
numList = randi(4, [1 2000]);  % Sample data
colorList = colors(numList);   % 1-by-2000 cell array of strings
```

Comment: Beat me by 15 seconds!

Comment: Ah easy, but never would have thought to try that, thanks.

Comment: Hey does there happen to be an easy way to map the same integer vector to a matrix where each row is one of four vector values like {[1 0 0], [0 0 1],[0 1 0],[0 0 0]}?

Comment: @Jake: If your vectors only contain integers, you could actually use a `containers.Map` object. I discuss one way to do this in the second part of [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43474582/52738). Basically, you need to turn your integer vectors into a character representation, since a character key is needed for the map. You could do this using functions like `char` (shown in the linked answer) or perhaps `sprintf` or `num2str`.